# VBA - Access FileSystemObject without Dimming it as an object

Tags: vba

I wonder if you can access an object without dimming it.
Example below:

In order to access the FileSystemObject I would access it in the following way:

```
Dim fso As Object
fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If fso.FolderExists("C:\Folder")
        msgbox "Folder exists"
    End If
```

I am looking for a way to access it without having to dim it.
Something along the lines of:

```
    If Scripting.FileSystemObject.FolderExists("C:\Folder")
        msgbox "Folder exists"
    End If
```

I have added the [Microsoft Scripting Runtime] as a reference to my project, if that helps with my issue.

Comment: try using `dir` https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dir.php

Comment: incidentally, you'd need a `Set` in front of the `fso = CreateObject` bit to make that example work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is also valid:

Late-bound:

```
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not .FolderExists(path_) Then .CreateFolder path_
End With
```

Early-bound (requires reference to the Scripting library):

```
With New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    If Not .FolderExists(path_) Then .CreateFolder path_
End With
```

Comment: This is the better solution. The `With` block cleanly scopes the object reference and ensures it's destroyed proper when execution exits the `With` block. Anything else leaves dangling object references that will be collected when VBA feels like it.

Comment: Could also be an early-bound `With New Scripting.FileSystemObject`, if you have a project reference to the scripting library - I've taken the liberty to edit your answer to that effect.

Comment: You guys are incredible, so awesome! Thanks for all the help! :)

Answer (score 4):

The following will work just fine:

```
Set myFolder = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFolder("C:\temp\")

WScript.Echo myFolder.Files.Count
```

Similarly, your example could be:

```
If CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").FolderExists("C:\Folder\") Then
    ' do something
End If
```

This will work fine as well.

You don't specifically need an object associated to the filesystemobject itself.  If however you are using `Option Explicit` (and I can't think of a good reason not to), then declaring your variables before use is enforced.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't even think of using the CreateObject in an if statement... This will do it for me.

Comment: @EliasWick a `With` block is a much cleaner solution. Here you're creating an object on the fly, and discarding the object reference. With a `With` block you ensure proper cleanup - here you rely on VBA to properly clean up after you.